# which property should be used to get the IP address of a connected user?

Tags: asp.net

which property should be used to get the ip address of a connected user
use property

Answer (score 3):

This should give you that:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: It is already of type `string`, so `.ToString()` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```